# How can I create a dataframe from a Series, based on specific condition?

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas, I have 2 Series' of similar lengths:

1. Series of floats in rising order (ex.: 1, 2, 3...100.4, ...1001, 1004.3..)
2. Series of Data points (floats)

additionally, I have 2 integers, "gap" and "range".

I want to create a new Dataframe based on the Data points conditionally using Series 1.
in the new Dataframe:

column1 will be all the data points from 1 to "range"

column2 will be all the data points from "gap" to "gap" + "range"

column3 will be all the data points from 2*"gap" to 2*"gap" + "range"

for example, if gap=100, range=1000:

column1 will be all the data points from (index of series1=1) to (index of series1=1000)

column2 will be all the data points from (index of series1=100) to (index of series1=1100)

column3 will be all the data points from (index of series1=200) to (index of series1=1200)

Comment: If you have two same length series you can just use a boolean `mask = (series1 >= gap) & (series1 <= gap + eange)`, Then use mask to get whatever you need. For example, `series2[mask]`.

Comment: Please add an example and expected output

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.